# Give the same rights to two users

Tags: permissions, multiple-users

Let's say I have 2 users :

user1 and user2

I would like to give user1 the same permissions as user2 but I don't want user2 having the same permission as user 1.

Sorry for my english.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll call user1 boss and user2 minion, to avoid the risk of typos that would invert the meaning).

You mean you want boss to be able to access minion's files? Add boss to the minion group. By default, on Ubuntu, most of minion's files are group-readable and group-writable. There's probably a way to do this in the GUI, but I only know the command line way:

```
sudo adduser boss minion
```

Minion can still create private files if he wants. If want to allow boss to run arbitrary commands as minion, this can be done through sudo. Run `sudo visudo` and add the following line:

```
boss ALL = (minion) ALL
```

Then boss can run `sudo -u minion somecommand`.

Comment: Thank you, user1 (boss) is the user that I use to login with SSH user2(minion) is www-data, the php user. Will it still works ?

Comment: @Babajaga Ah, no, that's a different use case. I thought you were talking about real users, not system users. For the www-data group, you'll need to make sure that Apache's umask is set to 002, I think the default is 022. [Set it in `/etc/apache2/envvars](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1536972). If you need more complex things, you might need [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List).

Comment: I dont see any line with umask 22 in the configuration file, do I have to create it ?

Comment: @Babajaga Yes, add a line with `umask 022` (and check whether it still applies to your version of Ubuntu).